# Inability to create Hotspot Using Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu, I just installed the latest ubuntu, the kinetic Kudu, but I have a challenge, I am unable to create an hotspot connection on my PC. Whenever I turn on the hotspot, I do not see the hotspot on my device. By the way, I am using an HP EliteBook 820 G1.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say "latest", do you mean 20.10 or 22.10? There's a pretty important difference between them ...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  *20.10 was groovy gorilla & not kinetic kudu !!*   FYI: Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, so 20.10 is the 2020-October release; 22.10 is the 2022-October release; you add 2000 to *year*

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.